# PostgreSQL - How to find the same value in multiple table and update the table?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have 2 tables as below **T1** and **T2** in PostgreSQL. I want to update the value of v2 and v3 in T1 according to value in T2. For example, both T1 and T2 share the same v1 value (1 and 2), therefore I want to pass the value of v2 and v3 in T2 (a,b,c,d) to T1.

**T1**

```
v1    v2    v3
1     NULL  NULL
2     NULL  NULL
3     NULL  NULL
```

**T2**

```
v1    v2    v3
1     a     b
2     c     d
4     e     f
```

Desired Output

**T1**

```
v1    v2    v3
1     a     b
2     c     d
3     NULL  NULL
```

This looks so simple, but I'm new in SQL, and so far I couldn't get the code right. I've tried to get the same value first before update the table, but it returns error.

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE
t1.v1 = t2.v1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking to use the `UPDATE ... FROM` syntax:

```
UPDATE t1 SET v2 = t2.v2, v3 = t2.v3 FROM t2 WHERE t1.v1=t2.v1;
```

Working example:

```
create table t1 (v1 int, v2 text, v3 text);
create table t2 (v1 int, v2 text, v3 text);
insert into t1 values (1,null,null),(2, null, null),(3, null,null);
insert into t2 values (1,'a','b'),(2,'c','d'),(4,'e','f');


postgres=# select * from t1;
 v1 | v2 | v3 
----+----+----
  1 |    | 
  2 |    | 
  3 |    | 
postgres=# UPDATE t1 SET v2 = t2.v2, v3 = t2.v3 FROM t2 WHERE t1.v1=t2.v1;
UPDATE 2
postgres=# select * from t1 order by v1;
 v1 | v2 | v3 
----+----+----
  1 | a  | b
  2 | c  | d
  3 |    |
```

And BTW, the correct `SELECT` syntax is:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1, t2
WHERE
t1.v1 = t2.v1
```

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](https://www.enterprisedb.com)